# How to create a Find/Replace Dialog box in MDI text editor using c#?

Tags: c#

I am using the following code for the find dialog (which is itself a separate form).
It gives Null refernce for While loop .Can anyone help what's wrong with this code or is it the right way to find text in a mdi editor?  Thanks

```
// Form1 is the main form having all editors functionalities

    private void findbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form1 f1 = new Form1();


                int index = 0;

                while (index < f1.GetRichtextbox().Text.LastIndexOf(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    f1.GetRichtextbox().Find(textBox1.Text,index,f1.GetRichtextbox().TextLength,RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                    f1.GetRichtextbox().SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    index = f1.GetRichtextbox().Text.IndexOf(f1.GetRichtextbox().Text, index) + 1;
                }


            }
```

Comment: You appear to be creating a new instance of Form1 and then using the rich text box on it without actually having done anything with the form.

Comment: On what line is the NullReferenceException being thrown?

Comment: NullRefernce appears on start of while loop.while (index < f1.GetRichtextbox().Text.LastIndexOf(textBox1.Text))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Form1 is the main form having all editors functionalities

Right...you need a reference to that actual instance of Form1 that is visible on the screen to the user.  Either pass a reference to it into your "find" dialog when you create it, or if your "find" dialog is also an MdiChild, use the MdiParent() property to get the main MDI form, then iterate over its MdiChildren() property until you find the instance of Form1 you need.

EDIT:

O.k., you can pass a reference to the MdiParent in the Show() command when you create and display your "find" form:

```
public partial class frmMdiParent : Form
{

    public frmMdiParent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void findToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmFind find = new frmFind();
        find.Show(this);
    }

}
```

Now, over in the "find" form, you can cast the Owner() property back to the MdiParent.  Use its ActiveMdiChild() property to get a reference to Form1:

```
public partial class frmFind : Form
{

    private frmMdiParent frmMDI = null;

    public frmFind()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += new EventHandler(frmFind_Shown);             
    }

    void frmFind_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Owner != null && this.Owner is frmMdiParent)
        {
            this.frmMDI = (frmMdiParent)this.Owner;
        }
    }

    private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.frmMDI != null && this.frmMDI.ActiveMdiChild is Form1)
        {
            Form1 frm1 = (Form1)this.frmMDI.ActiveMdiChild;
            // ... do something with "frm1" ...
            frm1.Text = "Hello from `frmFind`...";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I m still confused because i dont know how to pass reference to form1 and find dialog is a separate form its not MDI child.

Comment: Thanks a lot and +1  for such a brief description .I would try this.